# Angular2 FormGroup inside TR child component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have an `*ngFor` child row component in a table that I need to wrap with a FormGroup. Something like this.

```
<tr [formGroup]='dependentForm'>
  <td>
    <input type="text"  formControlName="first_name">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text"  formControlName="last_name">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" formControlName="dob">
  </td>
</tr>
```

But I can't figure out how to load the component from the parent template without it messing up the header columns alignment.

I've tried with an element selector and an attribute selector but there seems to be a roadblock either way. If I use an attribute selector, `<tr dependent-row>`, and remove the `tr` from the child I then can't wrap anything around my `input`s to assign a `formGroup` to or it messes up the columns. If I use an element selector `<dependent-row></dependent-row>` and put the `tr` inside the child component like the sample above, that just makes the table even worse by just listing all the `tr`s inline.

I hope I've described my problem well enough. Thanks for looking!

**UPDATE**

Here's an example using an attribute selector. The `tr` tags in the `dependent-row` component are throwing off the table columns but I need something to add a `formGroup` to so I'm not sure how to properly handle this.

https://plnkr.co/edit/oXxkUGKtVp0T1u4Qz8AX?p=preview

Here is the alternative method using an element selector.

https://plnkr.co/edit/qSLP5kVPLIWYdT19qset?p=preview

Comment: I'm don't understand what the problem is (might be only me). What about a Plunker that demonstrates what you try to accomplish and what problem you run into?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a fix, but not sure if it causes any side effect. I'm not the table man after all.

I think the problem is because you have nested `<tr>`, so I changed the outer `<tr>` to `<tbody>`:

```
<tbody dependent-row *ngFor="let dependent of dependents"
    [dependent]='dependent' >
```

Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/xxiGTcQvUaLruj9DIU5w?p=preview