# Table Rows in component in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I want to make a TableRowsComponent in angular 2 that renders to a number of table rows.

I would like to use it in a template like this:

```
<table class>
    <tbody>
        <table-rows *ngFor="#item of list" [someInput]="item"></table-rows>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

(So "table-rows" would be the selector of the TableRowsComponent here) The template of the TableRowsComponent would be something like:

```
<tr>
    <td> foo </td> 
    <td> bar </td>
</tr>
<tr *ngIf="something">
    ....
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="..">
     ...
</tr>
```

If we were to do this then the result looks like this:

```
<table class>
        <tbody>
            <table-rows>
                <tr>
                    ...
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    ...
                </tr> 
            </table-rows>
            <table-rows>
                <tr>
                    ...
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    ...
                </tr> 
            </table-rows> 
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Unfortunately the < table-rows > elements mess up the rendering of the table. How to solve this problem? Is there maybe a way to make angular2 not render the < table-rows > elements?

Comment: You may want to check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463346/angular2-formgroup-inside-tr-child-component/38470631#38470631

Comment: Thanks for the reference. It is almost a good solution, but if you check the plunkr there the solution has each < tr > ... < /tr > inside its own < tbody > ... < /tbody > :(

Answer (score 2):

you can use `[table-rows]` rather than `table-rows` when naming your selector.

e.g.

```
`@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: '[table-rows]',
    templateUrl: 'table-rows.component.html'
})`
```

and then simply use it within the tbody tag, ala `<tbody table-rows></tbody>`

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, NgForm, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
      selector: '[dependent-row]',
      providers: [],
      template: `
        <tr [formGroup]="dependentForm">
          <td>
            <input type="text" formControlName="foo">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" formControlName="bar">
          </td>
        </tr>
      `,
      directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES]
    })
    export class DependentRowComponent implements OnChanges {
      @Input() dependent: any;
      _Form: any;

      constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.dependentForm = fb.group({
          foo: [''],
          bar: [''],
        })
      }

      ngOnChanges() {
        this._Form.find('foo').updateValue(this.dependent.foo);
        this._Form.find('bar').updateValue(this.dependent.bar);
      }
    }
```

Comment: It is good that you are offering a solution, but your answer should always contain some explanation along with code. Thank you!

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.